# run a custom task using celery and redis in airflow using existing airflow setup

Tags: python, redis, celery, airflow

I have an airflow image which is configured to run tasks in parallel using celery and redis.

I want to run a task in one of the dags which will use the existing setup of airflow.

```
AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow  
AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
```

In a dag I am using python operator to create a celery task and get the result.

```
broker = os.environ["AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL"]
backend  = broker[:-1]+"1"#broker=redis://:@redis:6379/0 backend=redis://:@redis:6379/1
print(f'broker={broker} backend={backend}')

app = Celery('main',broker=broker, backend=backend )


@app.task
def maximum(x, y):
    print("here")
    print(x)
    if x > y:
      return x
    else:
      return y

#this is called from dag
def test():
    #max=maximum.apply_async(kwargs={'x':5, 'y':4})
    max1=maximum.delay(5,4)
    print(max1.get(timeout=5))
    return 0
```

When I execute above it is getting timedout.

```
celery.exceptions.TimeoutError: The operation timed out.
```

Is there a way to execute such tasks?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Why not just use a PythonOperator in Airflow?

Comment: I have used PythonOperator only but want to connect to  celery which is used by airflow and execute some my own tasks

Comment: Can anyone please help ? I need to add a self defined task instead of tasks defined in DAG to run from airflow.